# Extract multiple strings using regex

Tags: regex, string

I want to extract multiple strings from one string based on certain regex.

Example:

**Input String :**

> 20140909 Sample String 1 TRAINING COMPLETE useless string TRAINING COMPLETE useless string 2 TRAINING COMPLETE useless string 2 TRAINING COMPLETE 20120206 sample string 2 TRAINING COMPLETE

I want to extract the strings between the date string and TRAINING COMPLETE string.

**Expected Output of Above String is following two strings**

```
20140909 Sample String 1 TRAINING COMPLETE
20120206 Sample String 2 TRAINING COMPLETE
```

**Regex I am using:** (\d{8})(.*?)TRAINING COMPLETE
But this gives only the first required string, I want all the required strings.

Comment: What language/tool are you using ?

Comment: if you are using php use preg_match_all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the global modifier `g`

[Online Demo](http://regex101.com/r/oD2rK8/1)

```
/(\d{8})(.*?)TRAINING COMPLETE/g
```

- `g` stands for **g** lobal. It matches all and not just on first match